# Make several animation run in the same time

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/eYTdW/2/

```
var leftval = 0;
$.when(
$.each($(document).find("div"), function () {
    if ($(this).prop("id") != "four") {
        leftval += 100;
    } else {
        leftval += 200;
    }
    $(this).animate({
        left: leftval
    }, leftval * 20).promise();
})).done(function () {
    alert("done");
});
```

I want my divs to have the same speed and start moving in the same time. But it doesnt seem to work =( why?

Comment: You should be putting your code inside `$(document).ready` function... You are doing it right?

Comment: j809, I do... I just pointed out the area of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the default animation 'easing' of animation.  By default, animations start moving fast and get slower towards the end (easing 'swing').  To force your animations to move at a constant, linear, rate, you need to specify your animation's easing property to be 'linear'.

http://jsfiddle.net/eYTdW/4/

All I did was change your animation duration to an object that specifies the easing property to be linear:

```
var leftval = 0;
$.when(
$.each($(document).find("div"), function () {
    if ($(this).prop("id") != "four") {
        leftval += 100;
    } else {
        leftval += 200;
    }
    $(this).animate({
        left: leftval + 'px',
    }, 
    // CHANGE THIS HERE, it used to just be the leftval * 20 duration, now I specify the easing property as well.
    {
        duration: leftval * 20,
        easing: 'linear'
    }).promise();
})).done(function () {
    alert("done");
});
```

Linear easing makes the animation move from start to finish at a constant speed

Comment: This should be the answer. Voted